# Understanding DeepAr plot_prediction in pytorch forecasting

Tags: predict, forward, raw, pytorch-forecasting, deepar

I have tried the example of the pytorch forecasting DeepAR implementation as described in the [doc](https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/deepar.html).

There are two ways to create and plot predictions with the model, which give very different results. One is using the model's `forward()` function and the other the model's `predict()` function.

One way is implemented in the model's `validation_step()` method and is logged in tensorboard:

```
# validation step
idx = 0

prediction_kwargs = {}
prediction_kwargs.setdefault("n_samples", 20)
prediction_kwargs.setdefault("use_metric", True)

quantiles_kwargs = {}
quantiles_kwargs.setdefault("n_samples", 20)
quantiles_kwargs.setdefault("use_metric", True)
  
kwargs = dict(prediction_kwargs=prediction_kwargs, quantiles_kwargs=quantiles_kwargs)

x, y = next(iter(val_dataloader))
out = net(x, n_samples=None)
fig = net.plot_prediction(x, out, idx=idx, add_loss_to_title=True, **kwargs)
```

[After 5 epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr8UF.png)

The other way is described in the doc:

```
# doc
idx = 0

raw_prediction, x = net.predict(
    validation,
    mode="raw", return_x=True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = net.plot_prediction(x, raw_prediction, idx=idx, add_loss_to_title=True)
```

[After 5 epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMBlt.png)

I am using `pytorch=1.13.1`, `pytorch_lightning=1.8.6` and `pytorch_forecasting=0.10.2`.

Thanks for an input.

Answer (score 0):

The difference comes from the model's parameter `n_samples`, which is explicitly set to `None` in the first case, while it is implicitly set to `100` in the second case.

According to the code comment "If n_smaples [sic] is given, decode not by using actual values but rather by sampling new targets from past predictions iteratively". Hence with `n_samples=None`, the next time prediction is based on the *actual* value, and not the *predicted* value, of the current time.